# Why does keyboard-slide crash my app?

Tags: android, crash, viewflipper

If I physically slide out the keyboard on my Moto Droid A855, it crashes my test app with the stack trace pasted below. I don't understand why?

Also, if I start my app with the keyboard out, my app crashes immediately on startup.

The app consists of an activity, which contains a viewflipper as the main view layout. The viewflipper contains two linearlayouts...

Stack trace:

```
06-10 21:10:17.652 E/AndroidRuntime( 3785): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
06-10 21:10:17.668 E/AndroidRuntime( 3785): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Receiver not registered: android.widget.ViewFlipper$1@447af0b8
06-10 21:10:17.668 E/AndroidRuntime( 3785):     at android.app.ActivityThread$PackageInfo.forgetReceiverDispatcher(ActivityThread.java:667)
06-10 21:10:17.668 E/AndroidRuntime( 3785):     at android.app.ApplicationContext.unregisterReceiver(ApplicationContext.java:747)
06-10 21:10:17.668 E/AndroidRuntime( 3785):     at android.content.ContextWrapper.unregisterReceiver(ContextWrapper.java:321)
06-10 21:10:17.668 E/AndroidRuntime( 3785):     at android.widget.ViewFlipper.onDetachedFromWindow(ViewFlipper.java:104)
06-10 21:10:17.668 E/AndroidRuntime( 3785):     at android.view.View.dispatchDetachedFromWindow(View.java:5835)
06-10 21:10:17.668 E/AndroidRuntime( 3785):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDetachedFromWindow(ViewGroup.java:1076)
06-10 21:10:17.668 E/AndroidRuntime( 3785):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDetachedFromWindow(ViewGroup.java:1074)
06-10 21:10:17.668 E/AndroidRuntime( 3785):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDetachedFromWindow(ViewGroup.java:1074)
06-10 21:10:17.668 E/AndroidRuntime( 3785):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDetachedFromWindow(ViewGroup.java:1074)
06-10 21:10:17.668 E/AndroidRuntime( 3785):     at android.view.ViewRoot.dispatchDetachedFromWindow(ViewRoot.java:1570)
06-10 21:10:17.668 E/AndroidRuntime( 3785):     at android.view.ViewRoot.doDie(ViewRoot.java:2556)
06-10 21:10:17.668 E/AndroidRuntime( 3785):     at android.view.ViewRoot.die(ViewRoot.java:2526)
06-10 21:10:17.668 E/AndroidRuntime( 3785):     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.removeViewImmediate(WindowManagerImpl.java:218)
06-10 21:10:17.668 E/AndroidRuntime( 3785):     at android.view.Window$LocalWindowManager.removeViewImmediate(Window.java:436)
06-10 21:10:17.668 E/AndroidRuntime( 3785):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:3498)
06-10 21:10:17.668 E/AndroidRuntime( 3785):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3599)
06-10 21:10:17.668 E/AndroidRuntime( 3785):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:119)
06-10 21:10:17.668 E/AndroidRuntime( 3785):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1867)
06-10 21:10:17.668 E/AndroidRuntime( 3785):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-10 21:10:17.668 E/AndroidRuntime( 3785):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
06-10 21:10:17.668 E/AndroidRuntime( 3785):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4363)
06-10 21:10:17.668 E/AndroidRuntime( 3785):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-10 21:10:17.668 E/AndroidRuntime( 3785):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
06-10 21:10:17.668 E/AndroidRuntime( 3785):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
06-10 21:10:17.668 E/AndroidRuntime( 3785):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
06-10 21:10:17.668 E/AndroidRuntime( 3785):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-10 21:10:17.684 I/Process ( 1017): Sending signal. PID: 3785 SIG: 3
```

EDIT: added XML layout and relevant snippets from main activity.

Entire XML layout file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>


<ViewFlipper
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/vFlipper"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <!--  Linear Layout 1: messages and overview.  -->
                <LinearLayout
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    >

                <TableRow android:id="@+id/TableRow01" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                <TextView
                        android:text="Connection info"
                        android:id="@+id/tvCon1"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:background="#F0F0F0"
                        android:textColor="#FF0000"
                        />
                </TableRow>


                <ScrollView
                        android:id="@+id/ScrollView01"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="fill_parent">

                                <TextView  
                                        android:id="@+id/tvMessages"
                                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                                    android:text=""
                                    />

                </ScrollView>

        </LinearLayout>


        <!--  Linear Layout 2: settings -->
        <LinearLayout
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    >


                <TableRow
                        android:id="@+id/TableRow03"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                                <TextView
                                android:text="hello world"
                                android:id="@+id/asdfasdf2"
                                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                />
                </TableRow>                

        </LinearLayout>

</ViewFlipper>
```

Code snippets from Main Activity:

```
/**
 * Attempt (not currently working) to work around this bug: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=6191
 * TODO: make it work.
 */
@Override
public void onDetachedFromWindow() {
        Log.d("Dash","OnDetachedFromWindow()");

        try {
        super.onDetachedFromWindow();
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        ViewFlipper v = (ViewFlipper)findViewById(R.id.vFlipper);
        if (v != null) {
                Log.d("Dash","De-Bug hit. e=" + e.getMessage());
                v.stopFlipping();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

To resolve this issue you must

- Define a new class called `MyViewFlipper` which overrides `ViewFlipper` (see below)
- Reference that new class anywhere you would have previously referenced `ViewFlipper`
- Define your class and layout as shown below:

New class called `MyViewFlipper`. Contains the following:

```
package com.gtosoft.dash; // change this to match your own app. 

import android.content.Context;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.ViewFlipper;

public class MyViewFlipper extends ViewFlipper {

    public MyViewFlipper(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDetachedFromWindow() {
        try{
            super.onDetachedFromWindow();
        }catch(Exception e) {
            Log.d("MyViewFlipper","Stopped a viewflipper crash");
            stopFlipping();
        }
    }
}
```

Now to use this "fixed" version of `ViewFlipper` you have to reference it in the xml layout. Since it is basically a "custom view", you have to fully qualify the package path to `MyViewFlipper`, as seen here:

```
<com.gtosoft.dash.MyViewFlipper
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/vFlipper"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    (insert all the other old layout code here)

</com.gtosoft.dash.MyViewFlipper>
```

Now the app no longer crashes on the keyboard slide event or if the app is started with slide already out. Look for this in the log:

```
06-11 20:08:15.811 D/MyViewFlipper( 6106): Stopped a viewflipper crash
```

Credit: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=6191

Comment: I think I made a small typo - the <ViewFlipper needs to be <com.gtosoft.dash.MyViewFlipper

Comment: You're missing an important line: call stopFlipping() in the catch block so that it will call updateRunning().

Answer (score 5):

It's really difficult to help you if you don't provide some part of your code... anyway, this error is not new and there are some workarounds in order to solve it (I guess is some bug)... try to do this:

```
@Override
protected void onDetachedFromWindow() {
    try {
        super.onDetachedFromWindow();
    }
    catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        stopFlipping();
    }
}
```

This is for overriding the `onDetachedFromWindow` and I hope it works for you.

Comment: I tried implementing this fix last night but it had no affect. First off, Eclipse didn't like "protected" so I had to make it public. Also, stopFlipping needed to be qualified using findviewById, etc. And I put debug messages in the new code block and found it wasn't even firing, ever.

Comment: @Brad Could you share your code so that we can see if you are doing something wrong?

Comment: Found the problem: Per http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=6191 we need to create our own viewflipper wrapper by defining a new class that extends ViewFlipper. Call the new class MyViewFlipper. And anywhere I want to use a viewflipper, such as in layout XML, use the MyViewFlipper class which includes the fix code specified in the link I pasted.

Answer (score 2):

I know this question was asked almost two years ago, but since then a very easy fix has been implemented. Just add `android:configChanges="orientation|keyboard|keyboardHidden"` into each Activity call in the Manifest.

Answer (score 0):

yeah I don't see this bug before.. but then again I have this in my manifest

```
 <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|navigation"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:launchMode="singleTop" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>

</activity>
```