# Viewflipper Receiver not registered error while orientation change in 2.1 and 2.2

Tags: android, screen-orientation, viewflipper, android-sdk-2.1, android-2.2-froyo

I am using viewflipper for fling gesture recognition everything works fine for 2.0 and prior but in 2.2 and 2.1 it throws exception as "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Receiver not registered: android.widget.ViewFlipper" below is full debug trace.

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Receiver not registered: android.widget.ViewFlipper$1@452f8398
09-19 11:33:06.825: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(393):     at android.app.ActivityThread$PackageInfo.forgetReceiverDispatcher(ActivityThread.java:793)
09-19 11:33:06.825: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(393):     at android.app.ContextImpl.unregisterReceiver(ContextImpl.java:814)
09-19 11:33:06.825: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(393):     at android.content.ContextWrapper.unregisterReceiver(ContextWrapper.java:331)
09-19 11:33:06.825: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(393):     at android.widget.ViewFlipper.onDetachedFromWindow(ViewFlipper.java:104)
09-19 11:33:06.825: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(393):     at android.view.View.dispatchDetachedFromWindow(View.java:6033)
09-19 11:33:06.825: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(393):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDetachedFromWindow(ViewGroup.java:1158)
09-19 11:33:06.825: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(393):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDetachedFromWindow(ViewGroup.java:1156)
09-19 11:33:06.825: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(393):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDetachedFromWindow(ViewGroup.java:1156)
09-19 11:33:06.825: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(393):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDetachedFromWindow(ViewGroup.java:1156)
09-19 11:33:06.825: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(393):     at android.view.ViewRoot.dispatchDetachedFromWindow(ViewRoot.java:1630)
09-19 11:33:06.825: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(393):     at android.view.ViewRoot.doDie(ViewRoot.java:2671)
09-19 11:33:06.825: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(393):     at android.view.ViewRoot.die(ViewRoot.java:2641)
09-19 11:33:06.825: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(393):     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.removeViewImmediate(WindowManagerImpl.java:218)
09-19 11:33:06.825: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(393):     at android.view.Window$LocalWindowManager.removeViewImmediate(Window.java:436)
09-19 11:33:06.825: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(393):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:3684)
09-19 11:33:06.825: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(393):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3789)
09-19 11:33:06.825: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(393):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2400(ActivityThread.java:125)
09-19 11:33:06.825: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(393):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2037)
09-19 11:33:06.825: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(393):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-19 11:33:06.825: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(393):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
09-19 11:33:06.825: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(393):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
09-19 11:33:06.825: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(393):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-19 11:33:06.825: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(393):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
09-19 11:33:06.825: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(393):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
09-19 11:33:06.825: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(393):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
09-19 11:33:06.825: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(393):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

[There is issue on Google related to this bug 6191.](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=6191)

And the solutions mentioned in there seems to work only if your are creating ViewFlipper through code but in my case i am using ViewFlipper in XML which is my layout file and so i cant use the solution mentioned for extending the ViewFlipper i tried using delay nothing seems to work.

I am stuck awfully with this any help will be really appreciated.

Below is my layout code.

```
<ViewFlipper xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/flipper"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:id="@+id/parentView" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:background="@color/listingBG">
        <TextView 
                android:id="@+id/statusMessage" 
                android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                style="@style/TextLabel.Normal" android:visibility="gone" 
                android:text="No result" android:padding="15dp" android:gravity="center_horizontal"/>
        <ScrollView android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:scrollbars="none" android:id="@+id/scrollView" >
            <RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/parentItemView" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="fill_parent">
            </RelativeLayout>
        </ScrollView>
    </LinearLayout>
</ViewFlipper>
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can extend the ViewFlipper and use the full name of your new class (with package) in the xml layout file:

`<com.yourpackage.FixedViewFlipper>
   ...
</com.yourpackage.FixedViewFlipper>`

You can even create distinct xml files for 2.1 and 2.2 versions using a layout directory name like `res/layout-v7` and `res/layout-v8`.

Comment: I wish more people would start accepting the answers. Thanks Kevin.

Comment: will you provide me the sample code for same, because i not getting what are you saying "
<com.yourpackage.FixedViewFlipper> ... </com.yourpackage.FixedViewFlipper>"

Comment: I just got this exception, even though I have "android:screenOrientation="portrait"" in the manifest for this particular activity. How come?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem as described in this question.

After some searching I found this question which looks like to solved my this problem for me.
[Why does keyboard-slide crash my app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3019606/why-does-keyboard-slide-crash-my-app)