# Java Null pointer exception error in android

Tags: android, exception

My complete code and stack trace is attached in the below link for your kind reference.

http://pastebin.com/30vA30hM.

I get the following error:

> java.lang.NullPointerException at 
>   com.texter.messenger.SmsReceiverService$ServiceHandler.handleMessage(SmsReceiverService.java:116)

1. I also need help in Sending MMS thru my Android application. Any sample code will be of great help.
2. How can i display all the feeds from my Facebook account in facebook application along with my android application.

Thanks.

Comment: Please extract the relevant parts of your code and paste them here, along with the stack trace, rather than dumping hundreds of lines of code on external site.

Comment: post your logcat clearly and mention error line, just past code where your getting error..

Comment: I think you've changed the source code since the exception. Line 116 *cannot* produce a `NullPointerException`.

Comment: Step 1) Find out what was null (debuggers are handy). 2) Find out why it was null (brains are handy). 3) Fix it (hands are handy). 4) Drink a cold/hot [insert name of favorite beverage]. Delicious... and this question is far too localized.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/gZjD2Pts.. Please look into the code. I have edited and sent you where the error occurs. please tell me how to clear the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at your trace, this might be related to:

http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=6191

http://daniel-codes.blogspot.com/2010/05/viewflipper-receiver-not-registered.html

Apparently this is a problem that occurs on Android 2.1 and 2.2
Maybe try to run it in 2.3 and see if it's still happening?

Also that question and its answers might be of some help:

[Viewflipper Receiver not registered error while orientation change in 2.1 and 2.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3744954/viewflipper-receiver-not-registered-error-while-orientation-change-in-2-1-and-2)

Comment: pastebin.com/gZjD2Pts.. Please look into the code. I have edited and sent you where the error occurs. please tell me how to clear the error.