# How to debug the following android problem

Tags: android, debugging

The application that i'm working on has a problem, namely: When I start it everything is okay, but when I leave the program in landscape mode en then start it up again in portrait mode it gives a FC.

Is there a way to get debug information in this situation?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Google has a good [instructional guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/debugging/index.html).  Breakpoints/debugging and logcat (I prefer to monitor it by using `adb locat` in a command prompt window) are the best way to go.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I was using logcat via eclipse but via the command prompt I found my answer.

After some searching I found also the answer to this question which looks like to solved my this problem for me.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3019606/why-does-keyboard-slide-crash-my-app